# React Native | Auto Width 100%

Tags: react-native, styles

I am using React Native version 0.63.4. There is a bug that I just noticed and that didn't happen before. It does -width: '100%' - as if I added it myself to the style of any object (Text, View) I created. This was not the case before. For example, I want to paint the background of a text red. But just as much space as it is. Not all. I would add -width: '100%' - if I wanted this. But now it adds this automatically. What is the cause and solution?

[image: screenshot]

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <Text style={{marginTop: 80, backgroundColor: 'red'}}>EXAMPLE</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way because It will take full width by default, If you want to wrap then try adding `alignSelf:"flex-start"` like

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
  return (
    ...
      <Text style={{... , alignSelf:"flex-start"}}>EXAMPLE</Text>
    ...
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is a solution yes. This was not the case not so long ago. Do we have a chance to assign this as default to the whole project?

Comment: @aliosmankepir You can create a generic style like `AppStyle.js` and use it everywhere in the app. Please accept the answer if it helps thanks :-)